# Unable to install orjson 3.3.0 on macOS 12.2.1 with Apple M1 chip

Tags: python, macos, rust, apple-m1, orjson

I am trying to install `orjson==3.3.0` on my MacBook Pro with Apple M1 Pro chip running macOS Monterey 12.2.1.

Python version: `3.8.9`

Command used: `pip install orjson==3.3.0`

Error:

```
Collecting orjson==3.3.0
  Downloading orjson-3.3.0.tar.gz (654 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 654.9/654.9 KB 2.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [468 lines of output]
      Collecting maturin<0.9,>=0.8.1
        Downloading maturin-0.8.3.tar.gz (82 kB)
           ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 82.2/82.2 KB 1.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting toml~=0.10.0
        Using cached toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: maturin
        Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [443 lines of output]
            running bdist_wheel
            running build
            installing to build/bdist.macosx-10.14-arm64/wheel
            running install
                Updating crates.io index
             Downloading crates ...
              Downloaded mime_guess v2.0.3
              Downloaded net2 v0.2.34
              Downloaded num_cpus v1.13.0
              Downloaded once_cell v1.4.0
              Downloaded shlex v0.1.1
              Downloaded regex v1.3.9
              Downloaded socket2 v0.3.12
              Downloaded termcolor v1.1.0
              Downloaded podio v0.1.7
              Downloaded ppv-lite86 v0.2.8
              Downloaded proc-macro-nested v0.1.6
              Downloaded proc-macro-error-attr v1.0.4
              Downloaded semver v0.10.0
              Downloaded rand_chacha v0.2.2
              Downloaded serde_json v1.0.57
              Downloaded platform-info v0.0.1
              Downloaded quote v1.0.7
              Downloaded rand_core v0.5.1
              Downloaded ansi_term v0.11.0
              Downloaded tempfile v3.1.0
              Downloaded cc v1.0.58
              Downloaded scroll_derive v0.10.2
              Downloaded proc-macro-hack v0.5.18
              Downloaded textwrap v0.11.0
              Downloaded time v0.1.43
              Downloaded clap v2.33.3
              Downloaded unicode-width v0.1.8
              Downloaded httparse v1.3.4
              Downloaded crc32fast v1.2.0
              Downloaded try-lock v0.2.3
              Downloaded http-body v0.3.1
              Downloaded futures-sink v0.3.5
              Downloaded dtoa v0.4.6
              Downloaded hyper v0.13.7
              Downloaded serde v1.0.115
              Downloaded vec_map v0.8.2
              Downloaded matches v0.1.8
              Downloaded idna v0.2.0
              Downloaded strsim v0.8.0
              Downloaded proc-macro-error v1.0.4
              Downloaded digest v0.9.0
              Downloaded pin-project v0.4.23
              Downloaded rustc-demangle v0.1.16
              Downloaded slab v0.4.2
              Downloaded thiserror v1.0.20
              Downloaded thread_local v1.0.1
              Downloaded thiserror-impl v1.0.20
              Downloaded sha2 v0.9.1
              Downloaded want v0.3.0
              Downloaded untrusted v0.7.1
              Downloaded spin v0.5.2
              Downloaded scroll v0.10.1
              Downloaded percent-encoding v2.1.0
              Downloaded toml v0.5.6
              Downloaded tinyvec v0.3.3
              Downloaded tower-service v0.3.0
              Downloaded serde_urlencoded v0.6.1
              Downloaded same-file v1.0.6
              Downloaded structopt-derive v0.4.9
              Downloaded serde_derive v1.0.115
              Downloaded platforms v0.2.1
              Downloaded pin-project-lite v0.1.7
              Downloaded mime v0.3.16
              Downloaded glob v0.3.0
              Downloaded typenum v1.12.0
              Downloaded block-buffer v0.9.0
              Downloaded tar v0.4.29
              Downloaded unicode-bidi v0.3.4
              Downloaded unicode-segmentation v1.6.0
              Downloaded url v2.1.1
              Downloaded version_check v0.9.2
              Downloaded tokio-rustls v0.14.0
              Downloaded walkdir v2.3.1
              Downloaded xattr v0.2.2
              Downloaded tracing v0.1.19
              Downloaded pretty_env_logger v0.4.0
              Downloaded unicase v2.6.0
              Downloaded rand v0.7.3
              Downloaded unicode-xid v0.2.1
              Downloaded tracing-core v0.1.14
              Downloaded uuid v0.8.1
              Downloaded zip v0.5.6
              Downloaded webpki v0.21.3
              Downloaded sct v0.6.0
              Downloaded unicode-normalization v0.1.13
              Downloaded adler v0.2.3
              Downloaded anyhow v1.0.32
              Downloaded futures-io v0.3.5
              Downloaded futures-core v0.3.5
              Downloaded futures-task v0.3.5
              Downloaded tokio-util v0.3.1
              Downloaded semver-parser v0.7.0
              Downloaded hashbrown v0.8.2
              Downloaded rpassword v4.0.5
              Downloaded getrandom v0.1.14
              Downloaded heck v0.3.1
              Downloaded futures-macro v0.3.5
              Downloaded http v0.2.1
              Downloaded ipnet v2.3.0
              Downloaded itoa v0.4.6
              Downloaded human-panic v1.0.3
              Downloaded plain v0.2.3
              Downloaded log v0.4.11
              Downloaded memchr v2.3.3
              Downloaded miniz_oxide v0.4.0
              Downloaded mio v0.6.22
              Downloaded indexmap v1.5.1
              Downloaded futures-util v0.3.5
              Downloaded bzip2 v0.3.3
              Downloaded iovec v0.1.4
              Downloaded atty v0.2.14
              Downloaded cargo_metadata v0.11.1
              Downloaded cbindgen v0.14.3
              Downloaded winapi v0.3.9
              Downloaded webpki-roots v0.19.0
              Downloaded pin-project-internal v0.4.23
              Downloaded h2 v0.2.6
              Downloaded hyper-rustls v0.21.0
              Downloaded humantime v1.3.0
              Downloaded env_logger v0.7.1
              Downloaded structopt v0.3.16
              Downloaded goblin v0.2.3
              Downloaded pkg-config v0.3.18
              Downloaded autocfg v1.0.0
              Downloaded syn v1.0.38
              Downloaded rustls v0.18.1
              Downloaded object v0.20.0
              Downloaded pin-utils v0.1.0
              Downloaded opaque-debug v0.3.0
              Downloaded proc-macro2 v1.0.19
              Downloaded quick-error v1.2.3
              Downloaded bytesize v1.0.1
              Downloaded futures-channel v0.3.5
              Downloaded tokio v0.2.22
              Downloaded cfg-if v0.1.10
              Downloaded lazy_static v1.4.0
              Downloaded fnv v1.0.7
              Downloaded base64 v0.12.3
              Downloaded generic-array v0.14.4
              Downloaded filetime v0.2.12
              Downloaded remove_dir_all v0.5.3
              Downloaded backtrace v0.3.50
              Downloaded reqwest v0.10.7
              Downloaded bytes v0.5.6
              Downloaded bitflags v1.2.1
              Downloaded aho-corasick v0.7.13
              Downloaded os_type v2.2.0
              Downloaded flate2 v1.0.16
              Downloaded libc v0.2.74
              Downloaded bzip2-sys v0.1.9+1.0.8
              Downloaded addr2line v0.13.0
              Downloaded regex-syntax v0.6.18
              Downloaded gimli v0.22.0
              Downloaded ryu v1.0.5
              Downloaded encoding_rs v0.8.23
              Downloaded ring v0.16.15
               Compiling libc v0.2.74
               Compiling cfg-if v0.1.10
               Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.19
               Compiling unicode-xid v0.2.1
               Compiling syn v1.0.38
               Compiling version_check v0.9.2
               Compiling log v0.4.11
               Compiling memchr v2.3.3
               Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
               Compiling cc v1.0.58
               Compiling serde_derive v1.0.115
               Compiling serde v1.0.115
               Compiling itoa v0.4.6
               Compiling autocfg v1.0.0
               Compiling fnv v1.0.7
               Compiling getrandom v0.1.14
               Compiling bytes v0.5.6
               Compiling slab v0.4.2
               Compiling futures-core v0.3.5
               Compiling untrusted v0.7.1
               Compiling pin-project-internal v0.4.23
               Compiling spin v0.5.2
               Compiling pin-project-lite v0.1.7
               Compiling proc-macro-nested v0.1.6
               Compiling proc-macro-hack v0.5.18
               Compiling typenum v1.12.0
               Compiling once_cell v1.4.0
               Compiling ppv-lite86 v0.2.8
               Compiling pin-utils v0.1.0
               Compiling matches v0.1.8
               Compiling futures-sink v0.3.5
               Compiling ryu v1.0.5
               Compiling regex-syntax v0.6.18
               Compiling pkg-config v0.3.18
               Compiling tinyvec v0.3.3
               Compiling adler v0.2.3
               Compiling futures-io v0.3.5
               Compiling httparse v1.3.4
               Compiling base64 v0.12.3
               Compiling unicode-segmentation v1.6.0
               Compiling serde_json v1.0.57
               Compiling bitflags v1.2.1
               Compiling crc32fast v1.2.0
               Compiling try-lock v0.2.3
               Compiling termcolor v1.1.0
               Compiling quick-error v1.2.3
               Compiling gimli v0.22.0
               Compiling winapi v0.3.9
               Compiling tower-service v0.3.0
               Compiling percent-encoding v2.1.0
               Compiling unicode-width v0.1.8
               Compiling encoding_rs v0.8.23
               Compiling semver-parser v0.7.0
               Compiling vec_map v0.8.2
               Compiling remove_dir_all v0.5.3
               Compiling ansi_term v0.11.0
               Compiling object v0.20.0
               Compiling mime v0.3.16
               Compiling cbindgen v0.14.3
               Compiling anyhow v1.0.32
               Compiling strsim v0.8.0
               Compiling rustc-demangle v0.1.16
               Compiling dtoa v0.4.6
               Compiling same-file v1.0.6
               Compiling plain v0.2.3
               Compiling podio v0.1.7
               Compiling ipnet v2.3.0
               Compiling opaque-debug v0.3.0
               Compiling bytesize v1.0.1
               Compiling glob v0.3.0
               Compiling shlex v0.1.1
               Compiling platforms v0.2.1
               Compiling thread_local v1.0.1
               Compiling tracing-core v0.1.14
               Compiling unicase v2.6.0
               Compiling proc-macro-error-attr v1.0.4
               Compiling generic-array v0.14.4
               Compiling proc-macro-error v1.0.4
               Compiling hashbrown v0.8.2
               Compiling indexmap v1.5.1
               Compiling http v0.2.1
               Compiling ring v0.16.15
               Compiling futures-channel v0.3.5
               Compiling futures-task v0.3.5
               Compiling unicode-bidi v0.3.4
               Compiling miniz_oxide v0.4.0
               Compiling unicode-normalization v0.1.13
               Compiling heck v0.3.1
               Compiling humantime v1.3.0
               Compiling bzip2-sys v0.1.9+1.0.8
               Compiling textwrap v0.11.0
               Compiling walkdir v2.3.1
               Compiling addr2line v0.13.0
               Compiling http-body v0.3.1
               Compiling idna v0.2.0
               Compiling tracing v0.1.19
               Compiling want v0.3.0
               Compiling aho-corasick v0.7.13
               Compiling net2 v0.2.34
               Compiling iovec v0.1.4
               Compiling num_cpus v1.13.0
               Compiling time v0.1.43
               Compiling atty v0.2.14
               Compiling socket2 v0.3.12
               Compiling backtrace v0.3.50
               Compiling xattr v0.2.2
               Compiling filetime v0.2.12
               Compiling rpassword v4.0.5
            error: failed to run custom build command for `ring v0.16.15`
      
            Caused by:
              process didn't exit successfully: `/private/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/pip-install-ll07r0xs/maturin_0e5f2f37c0de4d1c8658d72a11487de2/target/debug/build/ring-e433715426729417/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
              --- stdout
              OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
              TARGET = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
              HOST = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
              CC_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
              CC_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
              HOST_CC = None
              CC = None
              CFLAGS_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
              CFLAGS_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
              HOST_CFLAGS = None
              CFLAGS = None
              CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
              DEBUG = Some("true")
              CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = None
      
              --- stderr
              ENV CARGO=/Users/admin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/cargo
              ENV CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ARCH=aarch64
              ENV CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ENDIAN=little
              ENV CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ENV=
              ENV CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FAMILY=unix
              ENV CARGO_CFG_TARGET_OS=macos
              ENV CARGO_CFG_TARGET_POINTER_WIDTH=64
              ENV CARGO_CFG_TARGET_VENDOR=apple
              ENV CARGO_CFG_UNIX=
              ENV CARGO_ENCODED_RUSTFLAGS=
              ENV CARGO_FEATURE_ALLOC=1
              ENV CARGO_FEATURE_DEFAULT=1
              ENV CARGO_FEATURE_DEV_URANDOM_FALLBACK=1
              ENV CARGO_FEATURE_ONCE_CELL=1
              ENV CARGO_HOME=/Users/admin/.cargo
              ENV CARGO_MAKEFLAGS=-j --jobserver-fds=8,10 --jobserver-auth=8,10
              ENV CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR=/Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15
              ENV CARGO_MANIFEST_LINKS=ring-asm
              ENV CARGO_PKG_AUTHORS=Brian Smith <brian@briansmith.org>
              ENV CARGO_PKG_DESCRIPTION=Safe, fast, small crypto using Rust.
              ENV CARGO_PKG_HOMEPAGE=
              ENV CARGO_PKG_LICENSE=
              ENV CARGO_PKG_LICENSE_FILE=LICENSE
              ENV CARGO_PKG_NAME=ring
              ENV CARGO_PKG_REPOSITORY=https://github.com/briansmith/ring
              ENV CARGO_PKG_VERSION=0.16.15
              ENV CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MAJOR=0
              ENV CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MINOR=16
              ENV CARGO_PKG_VERSION_PATCH=15
              ENV CARGO_PKG_VERSION_PRE=
              ENV DEBUG=true
              ENV DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/private/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/pip-install-ll07r0xs/maturin_0e5f2f37c0de4d1c8658d72a11487de2/target/debug/deps:/private/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/pip-install-ll07r0xs/maturin_0e5f2f37c0de4d1c8658d72a11487de2/target/debug:/Users/admin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib:/Users/admin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib:/Users/admin/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib
              ENV HOME=/Users/admin
              ENV HOST=aarch64-apple-darwin
              ENV LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
              ENV LOGNAME=admin
              ENV NUM_JOBS=10
              ENV OLDPWD=/Users/admin
              ENV OPT_LEVEL=0
              ENV OUT_DIR=/private/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/pip-install-ll07r0xs/maturin_0e5f2f37c0de4d1c8658d72a11487de2/target/debug/build/ring-74dfb65fdc90ab2c/out
              ENV PATH=/Users/admin/.cargo/bin:/private/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-w4ta8kth/overlay/bin:/private/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-w4ta8kth/normal/bin:/Users/admin/.cargo/bin:/Users/admin/venv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
              ENV PEP517_BUILD_BACKEND=setuptools.build_meta
              ENV PIP_REQ_TRACKER=/private/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/pip-req-tracker-179wcdnq
              ENV PLAT=macosx-10.14-arm64
              ENV PROFILE=debug
              ENV PS1=(venv) %n@%m %1~ %#
              ENV PWD=/Users/admin
              ENV PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1
              ENV PYTHONPATH=/private/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-w4ta8kth/site
              ENV RUSTC=rustc
              ENV RUSTDOC=rustdoc
              ENV RUSTUP_HOME=/Users/admin/.rustup
              ENV RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN=stable-aarch64-apple-darwin
              ENV RUST_RECURSION_COUNT=1
              ENV SHELL=/bin/zsh
              ENV SHLVL=1
              ENV SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.WMzJWaFIA5/Listeners
              ENV TARGET=aarch64-apple-darwin
              ENV TERM=xterm-256color
              ENV TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
              ENV TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=443
              ENV TERM_SESSION_ID=B8FDBA53-2516-4197-B600-445E738CFDEF
              ENV TMPDIR=/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/
              ENV USER=admin
              ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/Users/admin/venv
              ENV XPC_FLAGS=0x0
              ENV XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
              ENV _=/Users/admin/venv/bin/pip
              ENV _PIP_STANDALONE_CERT=/Users/admin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/certifi/cacert.pem
              ENV __CFBundleIdentifier=com.apple.Terminal
              ENV __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F7:0x0:0x0
              running "cc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-arch" "arm64" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-gfull" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/private/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/pip-install-ll07r0xs/maturin_0e5f2f37c0de4d1c8658d72a11487de2/target/debug/build/ring-74dfb65fdc90ab2c/out/aesv8-armx-linux64.o" "/Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S"
              /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:18:17: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
              .section .rodata
                              ^
              /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:28:1: error: unknown directive
              .hidden GFp_aes_hw_set_encrypt_key
              ^
              /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:29:1: error: unknown directive
              .type GFp_aes_hw_set_encrypt_key,%function
              ^
              /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:161:1: error: unknown directive
              .size GFp_aes_hw_set_encrypt_key,.-GFp_aes_hw_set_encrypt_key
              ^
              /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:163:1: error: unknown directive
              .hidden GFp_aes_hw_encrypt
              ^
              /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:164:1: error: unknown directive
              .type GFp_aes_hw_encrypt,%function
              ^
              /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:191:1: error: unknown directive
              .size GFp_aes_hw_encrypt,.-GFp_aes_hw_encrypt
              ^
              /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:193:1: error: unknown directive
              .hidden GFp_aes_hw_decrypt
              ^
              /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:194:1: error: unknown directive
              .type GFp_aes_hw_decrypt,%function
              ^
              /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:221:1: error: unknown directive
              .size GFp_aes_hw_decrypt,.-GFp_aes_hw_decrypt
              ^
              /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:223:1: error: unknown directive
              .hidden GFp_aes_hw_ctr32_encrypt_blocks
              ^
              /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:224:1: error: unknown directive
              .type GFp_aes_hw_ctr32_encrypt_blocks,%function
              ^
              /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:403:1: error: unknown directive
              .size GFp_aes_hw_ctr32_encrypt_blocks,.-GFp_aes_hw_ctr32_encrypt_blocks
              ^
              /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:407:19: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
              .section .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
                                ^
              thread 'main' panicked at 'execution failed', /Users/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.15/build.rs:664:9
              note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
            warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
            error: build failed
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/tmpwhciv39r", line 363, in <module>
                main()
              File "/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/tmpwhciv39r", line 345, in main
                json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
              File "/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/tmpwhciv39r", line 261, in build_wheel
                return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
              File "/private/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-w4ta8kth/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 208, in build_wheel
                return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
              File "/private/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-w4ta8kth/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 194, in _build_with_temp_dir
                self.run_setup()
              File "/private/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-w4ta8kth/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
                exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
              File "setup.py", line 81, in <module>
                setup(
              File "/private/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-w4ta8kth/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
                return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
              File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
                dist.run_commands()
              File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
                self.run_command(cmd)
              File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/private/var/folders/jl/9g_fqrr101g_s9y5jjns3rvc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-w4ta8kth/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 228, in run
                self.run_command('install')
              File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
                self.distribution.run_command(command)
              File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "setup.py", line 58, in run
                subprocess.check_call(
              File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
                raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
            subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cargo', 'rustc', '--bin', 'maturin', '--', '-C', 'link-arg=-s']' returned non-zero exit status 101.
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for maturin
      Failed to build maturin
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for maturin, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have tried looking around and stumbled upon the following posts:

- [Does Poetry install --no-dev need Rust to be installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61029467/does-poetry-install-no-dev-need-rust-to-be-installed)
- [requirement.txt installation is failing while building "orjson" on 64 bit python interpreter on 64 bit Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65081761/requirement-txt-installation-is-failing-while-building-orjson-on-64-bit-python)

However, it did not really help. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you could use `--verbose` to see more details - `pip install --verbose orjson==3.3.0`. Maybe it needs to install compile C/C++/Rust or some C/C++/Rust libraries or header files. And maybe `--verbose` shows some details which could explain problem.

Comment: On Python 3.10, oddly enough, I get a completely different error, but Python 3.9 installed cleanly, as did 3.8. Have you installed rust (`brew install rustup && rustup-init`)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that helps you but I had a similar Problem with 3.6.2, so I ran pip install orjson and it installed orjson==3.8.1 without a Problem.

Answer (score -1):

brew install rustup && rustup-init

this works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).